# How to add Supabase Order by in get request using Postman

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, postgrest

**I need to add order in supabase result while calling the supabase bash in postman.**

I am doing same in flutter like below

```
Future getPropertiesFromBirmingham() async {
    var response = await client
        .from('properties')
        .limit(10)
        .order('created_at', ascending: false);

    return response;
  }
```

Need to use same in postman but not getting anything on this.

I didn't find much on this topic, Tried using order in params but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can get examples of cURL requests directly in [Supabase API docs](https://app.supabase.com/project/_/api).
You can also check for more documentation directly in the [PostgREST](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=limit#limits-and-pagination) website.

```bash
curl 'https://supabase_project_ref.supabase.co/rest/v1/properties?limit=10&order=created_at.desc' \
-H "apikey: SUPABASE_KEY" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer SUPABASE_KEY"
```

You can also control where the NULLs will be (if any) by adding either of the following:

- `nullslast`
- `nullsfirst`

```bash
curl 'https://supabase_project_ref.supabase.co/rest/v1/properties?order=created_at.desc.nullslast' \
-H "apikey: SUPABASE_KEY" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer SUPABASE_KEY"
```